# Using RegionFunction with non-trivial Inequality

Tags: plotting, functions

So I have been using `ContourPlot` to plot the zero set of a fairly unwieldy function, with many intersecting components.  There's really only one of these components that I want to look at, so I realized there's an inequality constraint that will let me plot only the component I want.  Now, I know that this calls for `RegionFunction` but, I'm either implementing it very incorrectly, or my functions are so ugly that it won't work.  Regardless, I was hoping I could maybe get some tips to get this running.  My code is:

`M = 1;
tau = (0.5) + (0.5)*I;
w1 = Pi/2;
w2 = Pi*(tau)/2;
inv = N[WeierstrassInvariants[{w1, w2}]];
E2[t_] := 
  1 - 24*Sum[(n*Exp[2*Pi*I*(t)*n])/(1 - Exp[2*Pi*I*(t)*n]), {n, 1, 
      300}];
z[u_?NumericQ] := (I*
     M/2)*(WeierstrassZeta[u, inv] - ((1/3)*N[E2[tau], 50]*(u)));
WP[x_, y_] := WeierstrassP[w1*x + w2*y, inv];
L = -(1/3)*N[E2[tau], 50];
f[x_, y_] := Re[WP[x, y] - L];
g[x_, y_] := Im[WP[x, y] - L];
V1 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0.8}, {y, 0.5}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V2 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 1.2}, {y, 1.5}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V3 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0.8}, {y, -1.5}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V4 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 1.2}, {y, -0.5}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
A1 = x /. V1;
B1 = y /. V1;
A2 = x /. V2;
B2 = y /. V2;
A3 = x /. V3;
B3 = y /. V3;
A4 = x /. V4;
B4 = y /. V4;
Z1 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A1 + w2*B1], 50]]
Z2 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A2 + w2*B2], 50]]
Z3 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A3 + w2*B3], 50]]
Z4 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A4 + w2*B4], 50]]
m = (Im[Z1] - Im[Z2])/((Re[Z1] - Re[Z2]));
Zed[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := z[w1*x + w2*y];
Quiet[ContourPlot[{Im[
      N[Zed[x, y]]] - (m*(Re[N[Zed[x, y]]] - Re[(M/2)]) - Im[M/2]) == 
    0}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -4, 4}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.1], Specularity[White, 30]], 
  PlotPoints -> 75, WorkingPrecision -> 50, ClippingStyle -> None], 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, Abs[Zed[x, y] - M/2] <= Abs[Z2 - M/2]]]`

The last part of the script is where I attempt to use `RegionFunction` in `ContourPlot`.  The error I get is something to the effect of "Argument 2 of....should be All, None, a message name, or a list of message names."

Can anyone see where I'm going so wrong here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you feed `RegionFunction` to `Quiet[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I had the `Quiet` there before as I thought it's only purpose was to suppress any tolerable error messages.  I just removed the `Quiet` and got a single, but different error this time; it says: "...is incomplete, more input it needed."  In addition, my entry of `PlotStyle` is highlighted red.  Any idea what input I'm missing here?

Comment: Here's a quick way of checking: triple-click the symbol `ContourPlot` in your notebook to check if you're passing options to the right function.